# Very slow bitmap heap scan in Postgres

Tags: performance, postgresql, indexing

I have the following simple table that contains traffic measurement data:

```
CREATE TABLE "TrafficData"
(
  "RoadID" character varying NOT NULL,
  "DateID" numeric NOT NULL,
  "ExactDateTime" timestamp NOT NULL,
  "CarsSpeed" numeric NOT NULL,
  "CarsCount" numeric NOT NULL
)
CREATE INDEX "RoadDate_Idx" ON "TrafficData" USING btree ("RoadID", "DateID");
```

The column RoadID uniquely identifies the road whose data is being recorded, while DateID identifies the day of the year (1..365) of the data - basically a rounded off representation of ExactDateTime.

I have about 100.000.000 rows; there are 1.000 distinct values in the column "RoadID" and 365 distinct values in the column "DateID".

I then run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM "TrafficData"
WHERE "RoadID"='Station_1'
AND "DateID">20100610 AND "DateID"<20100618;
```

This takes up to three mind-boggling seconds to finish, and I cannot for the life of me figure out WHY.

EXPLAIN ANALYZE gives me the following output:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on "TrafficData"  (cost=104.84..9743.06 rows=2496 width=47) (actual time=35.112..2162.404 rows=2016 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: ((("RoadID")::text = 'Station_1'::text) AND ("DateID" > 20100610::numeric) AND ("DateID" < 20100618::numeric))
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "RoadDate_Idx"  (cost=0.00..104.22 rows=2496 width=0) (actual time=1.637..1.637 rows=2016 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((("RoadID")::text = 'Station_1'::text) AND ("DateID" > 20100610::numeric) AND ("DateID" < 20100618::numeric))
Total runtime: 2163.985 ms
```

My specs:

- Windows 7
- Postgres 9.0
- 4GB RAM

I'd greatly appreciate any helpful pointers!

Comment: This is not the table you are using, there is no "StationId" column.

Comment: Ah, true; thanks for pointing that out. StationID==RoadID. My bad. I just changed the column name in the table definition to make the contents more intuitive, but failed to change the name in the query definition and the query output. I've updated the question to include the correct column name.

Comment: Do you have vacuum running, or you've disabled that?

Comment: I think it's on, but this is just a test table that isn't updated: I created the table, added 100.000.000 dummy rows, and am now trying to find a quick way to access the data.

Comment: Try running analyze on this table and check the results. I've made some test table, with only 10M of rows. My Postgres runs using only 24MB for shared buffers. My explain analyze shows about 1-2ms.

Comment: @Simon autovacuum should be on by default, I think since 8.3 or 8.4

Comment: @TroutKing: the 100M dummy rows... how did you create the data?  If each record has the same value for a field, an index scan will actually take longer.

Comment: @vol7ron yea, should be, but I saw databases where people switched that off (just because it makes the database slower :) )

Comment: @vol7ron Good idea, maybe there is just stupid data. I has much better results as I just wrote a simple function that generates nice set of 10M random rows.

Comment: :) I love the With Recursive... so easy to create random records now :)

Comment: @Simon: ANALYZE gives me this: "TrafficData": scanned 30000 of 978740 pages, containing 3210000 live rows and 0 dead rows; 30000 rows in sample, 104725180 estimated total rows.

Comment: @Vol7ron: CarsSpeed and CarsCount always contain random values.

Comment: Have you tried to disable bitmap index scans? (SET enable_bitmapindexscan TO false)

Comment: Also, index can be made unique. It can also speed up query a bit.

Comment: @valodzka: The index scans themselves seem to be fairly fast; it's the subsequent heap scan that's slow. Also, I can't use unique indexes since the values in the indexed columns are decidedly non-unique.

Comment: @TroutKing: Those two fields are meaningless.  It's the indexed fields that matter about different data.  If the date is the same for all 100M records, then the need to search an index table is meaningless.  Also, what kind of cpu are you running?  It could be that you've hit your max performance at 2100ms.  Though psql is always faster than mysql for me, you should compare the two; since you are doing this on a desktop.

Comment: @vol7ron: I *was* wondering how CarsSpeed and CarsCount could possibly be relevant. ;) I have 365 distinct values for DateID and 1000 distinct values for RoadID, all of which are equally distributed in my dummy data. Never thought about CPU being maxed out... but I've just checked: CPU usage is never more than 20%.

Comment: So the limiting factor could be your hard drive or memory, but 100M records to search is no small amount.  For a desktop PC, I think 2secs is a decent response time, especially searching two where conditions.

Answer (score 4):

The slow part is obviosly fetching the data from the tables, since the index access seems to be very fast. You might either optimize your RAM usage parameters (see http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization and http://www.varlena.com/GeneralBits/Tidbits/perf.html), or optimize the layout of the data in the table by issuing a CLUSTER command (see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-cluster.html).

```
CLUSTER "TrafficData" USING "RoadDate_Idx";
```

should do it.

Comment: I tried this out yesterday, but had to give up when the CLUSTER command was still running after eleven hours.

Comment: Holla... Maybe a simple sorted select into another might be faster? If CLUSTER is that slow, it really seems to be an io problem, and the data does not seem to match the index at all. If you can, try this on server class hardware...

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Daniel's answer, the cluster operation is a one off process that rearranged the data on disk. The intent is to get your 2000 results rows from fewer disk blocks.

As this is dummy data, being used to find out how you can quickly query it, I'd recommend reloading it, in a pattern closer to how it will be loaded as it is generated. I imagine that the data is generated one day at a time, which will effectively result in strong correlation between `DateID` and the location on disk. If that is the case, then I'd either cluster by `DateID`, or split your test data into 365 separate loads, and reload it.

Without that, and having randomly generated data, you're most likely having to perform over 2000 seeks of your disk head.

I'd also check that anything else you're running on Windows 7 isn't adding time to those reads that you don't need, such as ensuring that the blocks read do not contain virus signatures, or concurrently performing an automatically scheduled disk defragmentation (resulting in the disk head hardly ever being anywhere close to where it was last time a database block was read).

Answer (score 0):

- 4GB RAM -> 6+ you have 100M records, which isn't large but for a desktop machine memory could matter.  If this is not a desktop, I'm not sure why you would have such a small amount of memory
- `AND "DateID">20100610 AND "DateID"<20100618;` -> `DateID BETWEEN 20100611 AND 20100617;`
- Create an index on the DateID
- Get rid of all the double quotes around field names
- Instead of a VarChar, make `RoadID` a text field

Comment: RAM upgrade isn't an option, unfortunately. More RAM also shouldn't really make any difference, since the index files are already "small" enough to load into memory. I've also tried DateID BETWEEN, sadly made no difference.

Comment: well you also want to create an index on the DateID; see the additions

Comment: Right, I've added an index on DateID. Sadly no difference.